# Switching from SQLite to Mysql in production causes error

Tags: mysql, python, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I am using a digital ocean server. After switching to mysql database from sqlite, I got `502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)`

This is running fine when I run the project from the terminal using `python manage.py runserver ip:8000`  . I think there are faults in the gunicorn .

How to solve this any idea?

After checking the logs,

```
sudo tail -F /var/log/nginx/error.log


2021/12/06 10:32:06 [error] 230230#230230: *15355 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 113.199.220.31, server: develop-330.gsa-cs.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "develop-330.gsa-cs.com"
2021/12/06 10:37:21 [error] 230230#230230: *15358 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 113.199.220.31, server: develop-330.gsa-cs.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "develop-330.gsa-cs.com"
2021/12/06 10:37:24 [error] 230230#230230: *15358 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 113.199.220.31, server: develop-330.gsa-cs.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "develop-330.gsa-cs.com"
2021/12/06 10:44:06 [error] 230230#230230: *15365 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 113.199.220.31, server: develop-330.gsa-cs.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "develop-330.gsa-cs.com"
2021/12/06 10:48:35 [error] 230230#230230: *15368 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 113.199.220.31, server: develop-330.gsa-cs.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "develop-330.gsa-cs.com"
2021/12/06 10:49:10 [notice] 1347821#1347821: signal process started
2021/12/06 10:49:15 [error] 1347822#1347822: *15371 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 113.199.220.31, server: develop-330.gsa-cs.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "develop-330.gsa-cs.com"
2021/12/06 10:51:10 [error] 1347822#1347822: *15374 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 113.199.220.31, server: develop-330.gsa-cs.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "develop-330.gsa-cs.com"
2021/12/06 10:56:54 [error] 1347822#1347822: *15377 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 113.199.220.31, server: develop-330.gsa-cs.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "develop-330.gsa-cs.com"
2021/12/06 11:00:09 [error] 1347822#1347822: *15381 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 113.199.220.31, server: develop-330.gsa-cs.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "develop-330.gsa-cs.com"
```

Comment: Can you please provide some logs? It's difficult to help you with so little information

Comment: nginx logs are added.

Comment: Even if you get past the connection problems, have you verified that the SQL syntax is the same?

Comment: Yes it's working on local as well as I run from terminal in production